# Set the frame of UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have problem with Activity Indicator…
if i am set the frame of Indicator is show the black background behind UIActivity indicator. and if i not set frame its look well but not in proper position. now how can i set Indicator to proper position?

Comment: And what's the code you use to do these things? Post it here!

Comment: Is there the same result when you use center instead of frame?

Comment: hi mbehan, i used center now its work ..:) thanks for give me idea.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its work well with this code..

```
activityIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

[activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(w/2-5,w/2-5)];

[activityIndicator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Answer (score 1):

Addind to @Raj answer.
Rather than calculating 'w' and pasing them in `CGPointMake`, you can use bound property.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(yourView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(yourView.bounds));
[yourView addSubview:indicator];
```